# Derive LinkedIn profile URL from user ID?

Tags: linkedin-api

Is it possible to derive a linkedin profile url (public OR private) from the user ID?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use the `ID` in this URL and this will give you the link to User Profile `http://www.linkedin.com/profile/view?id=YourID`

UPDATE: Apparently, this solution no longer works.

Comment: Jordan- This is the right answer to my question as worded- but I actually have a different problem as the LinkedIn API uses alphanumeric token IDs which don't work in this format...- see new question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11296484/165673

Comment: As tested right now, this works with the api ids, too. It will map the api-id to another internal id for you when you visit the link.

Comment: No it doesn't. All my tests have it mapping to your own ID by default, not to the member owning the API id.

Comment: For some reason, this doesn't work for me. I get this error `There was an unexpected problem that prevented us from completing your request.`, any idea why this is so?

Comment: They've removed this, sadly. Lookup by member ID no longer works.

Comment: Seems solution below is not working anymore. Who know another way to get profile link from user id?

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me.. I have added another updated solution that worked for me..

Answer (score 7):

You need to get `r_basicprofile` permissions from the user, then grab the `public-profile-url` field from the response.

read more at https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields/basic-profile

Answer (score 0):

You can get the linkedin url using the below format if you have the user id.

> https://www.linkedin.com/in/userID/

Replace the userID with linkedin user id.

Thank you!

Answer (score -2):

I guess some things have changed in the LinkedIn API over the years.

This is the solution that worked for me:

```
http://www.linkedin.com/in/USERNAME
```

Used it as a href in my website to link to user's LinkedIn profile page and it works fine.

Comment: But how can we get `username` from `memeber-id` eg `129056251`