# Derive LinkedIn profile URL from API user token?

Tags: linkedin-api

The LinkedIn API refers to users by alphanumeric member token instead of numeric ids.

Is it possible to derive a linkedin profile url (public OR private) from the user token?

(Info: https://developer.linkedin.com/comment/4173#comment-4173)

Answer (score 4):

Since you are already using the API to pull the [`id` field](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-fields#profile), why not just directly pull the `public-profile-url` as well?

On the hexadecimal nature of the member id, those strings are uniquely generated on a per application basis, so there is no way to map them directly to the corresponding id number used on LinkedIn.com.

Comment: You can pull and store the public profile url, but that's annoying and un-RESTful, and you can't do it when you're pulling things like connections on people search. Anyway, there *is* a way to map straight form the token- see my answer

Comment: I never suggested storing the url, which as you mention would be unRESTful. Good find on the method you answered with.